# Get the index of an object in an array whose type we do not know

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, linq

There is a list of values of type "book", and there is an object of type "book". The type of the sheet and the object before the function is executed is unknown, only in the process. When using the "indexOf ()" method, it gives the index -1, instead of 3 (checked when a sheet and object are rigidly typed by the type "book"). Conventionally, I have a bare leaf and a bare object, without properties and variables. Only after execution, objects get types and values. In progress. That's the whole difficulty
What's the catch?

```
//Object with id = 4, has index 3 in the list
obj = Connector.Get(CurrentTable, "WHERE Id = " + id).FirstOrDefault();

//list with 10 records
var list = Connector.Get(CurrentTable, Condition).ToList();

//Need get 3, got -1
var currIndex = list.IndexOf(obj);
var nextIndex = (currIndex < list.Count - 1 ? currIndex : -1) + 1;
var prevIndex = (currIndex > 0 ? currIndex : list.Count) - 1;

ViewBag.NextPost = list[nextIndex];
ViewBag.PrevPost = list[prevIndex];
```

Comment: IndexOf(obj) will not work.  IndexOf needs a compare method that is capable of comparing every property to each instance.  I doubt you have search a method.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What is `Connector.Get`? Apparently t doesn't know about generics (around since 2005) and Identity Map (common pattern in many data layer implementations).

Comment: You are trying to compare binary objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's comparing the object reference. You'd have to do something other than direct equality. Can you compare an Id property or something else to determine if they're equal?

```
//Object with id = 4, has index 3 in the list
obj = Connector.Get(CurrentTable, "WHERE Id = " + id).FirstOrDefault();

//list with 10 records
var list = Connector.Get(CurrentTable, Condition).ToList();

var currIndex = list
.Select((a, i) => new {element = a, index = i})
.First(a => a.element.Id == obj.Id)//or some other comparison that you would define as equal
.index;
var nextIndex = (currIndex < list.Count - 1 ? currIndex : -1) + 1;
var prevIndex = (currIndex > 0 ? currIndex : list.Count) - 1;

ViewBag.NextPost = list[nextIndex];
ViewBag.PrevPost = list[prevIndex];
```

Comment: `a => a.element.Id == obj.Id`. It does not work, because it does not see these elements (operator "." Cannot be applied to operand of type "lambda expression")

Comment: Conventionally, I have a bare leaf and a bare object, without properties and variables. Only after execution, objects get types and values. In progress. That's the whole difficulty

Comment: @Zicise Your question is incomplete because we don't know the types involved. If you want an answer to address you specific problem, describe it specifically. [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of any kind, like this one...

```
var list = Connector.Get(CurrentTable, Condition).ToList();
```

You can restrict the list to just objects of type "book" like this:

```
var books = list.OfType<book>().ToList();
```

Filtering it also casts it, so you can compare properties easily. If `class book` has a property `Id` and you're searching for a book that matches `obj`, you could do this:

```
var foundBook = books.First( b => b.Id == obj.Id );
```